# Check whether Elementor visual editor view is active

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

**How do I check whether a WordPress page is currently viewed "as a regular page" or "in the Elementor visual editor"?**

I've written a plugin that redirects users when a specific shortcode if present on a page. It works like a charm, but unfortunately the Elementor visual editor dies when a page redirects the client. I want the plugin to redirect only when the Elementor editor isn't active.

My first idea was to check if the URL contains `action=elementor`, as it does when Elementor editor is active, and do something like this:

```
global $wp;
if ( strpos(home_url( $wp->request ), 'action=elementor') !== false ) {
    // don't redirect
}
```

but this does not work, as `home_url( $wp->request )` only returns the permalink of the page but not the actually called URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay nevermind... This does the trick:

```
if ( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'elementor') !== false ) {
    // don't redirect
}
```

Comment: It's alright not 100 percent accurate but good thinking

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
  if ( \Elementor\Plugin::$instance->preview->is_preview_mode() ) {
    //do something
  } else {
   //do something
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try two methods below. this is the correct way to check.

```
// Check if Elementor's editor mode is active
if ( \Elementor\Plugin::$instance->editor->is_edit_mode() ) {
    // The code here will run when the Elementor editor mode is active
} else {
    // The code here will run when the Elementor editor mode is not active
}

// Check if Elementor's preview mode is active
if ( \Elementor\Plugin::$instance->preview->is_preview_mode() ) {
    // The code here will run when the Elementor preview mode is active
} else {
    // The code here will run when the Elementor preview mode is not active
}
```

Comment: I get this error when trying this method - PHP Fatal error Uncaught Error: Class 'Elementor\Plugin' not found

Comment: @prateek which version you are using? try updating your plugin.